# What's the best way to use back references?

Tags: javascript, regex

In some `\1` will work and in some `$1` in online regex builder.

Does both way works in every javascript engine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one way works in JavaScript, and it differs if the back-reference is in the regular expression (`\n`) or the replacement value (`$n`).

See [MDN Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> [In a regular expression] where `n` is a positive integer, [`\n` refers to] a back reference to the last substring matching the `n` parenthetical in the regular expression (counting left parentheses).
>
> For example, `/apple(,)\sorange\1/` matches 'apple, orange,' in "apple, orange, cherry, peach."
>
> ..
>
> The `\1` and `\2` in the pattern match the string's last two words. Note that `\1, \2, \n` are used in the matching part of the regex. *In the replacement part of a regex the syntax `$1, $2, $n` must be used*, e.g.: `'bar foo'.replace( /(...) (...)/, '$2 $1')`.

That way *is* the correct way in JavaScript; different regular expressions may work differently, but such is irrelevant to JavaScript code which works as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Backreferences, cannot be used inside a [`character class`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). The `\1` in a regex like `(a)[\1b]` is either an error or a needlessly escaped literal 1. In [`JavaScript`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) it's an [`octal escape`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html#octal).

It's better explained at [Using Regular Expressions with JavaScript - regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)